# Status Bar becomes white in iOS when using UISearchController in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

have a weird situation here. When I use the `UISearchController`, I get this appearance first (as expected)

[image]

But when you select inside the TextField to start searching, the Status Bar becomes completely white (or black if you are in dark mode)

[image]

This never used to happen. Is there some setting in `UISearchController` that tells it to use a certain Status Bar style when using the Search Bar?

I'd prefer it stay the color it was before selecting the TextField

***---EDIT---***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    frc = getFRC()
    frc.delegate = self

    self.resultsSearchController.delegate = self
    let searchBar = self.resultsSearchController.searchBar

    self.resultsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultsSearchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultsSearchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    searchBar.placeholder = "Catalog Search"
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkAqua
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    searchBarHeight = searchBar.frame.height

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        error.tryError(tryMessage: "Perform initial fetch", loc: self)
    }

    if tutorials.catalog {
        createTutorialTab(segueNameOnOpen: "catalogTutorial")
    }
}
```

Comment: If keyboard comes up, you adjusting frames? That might be one of the problem.

Comment: Nope, nothing adjusting frames.

Comment: Are you changing properties of the status bar or nav bar? i.e .backgroundColor = .white?

Comment: No, nothing there either. I'll post my `viewDidLoad` above

Comment: just a hunch.. can you try using this line self.resultsSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

Comment: That works perfectly Nicolas, and I like that the navigation bar stays now. Didn't know that was an option. You should stick that as an answer so I can mark you correct

Answer (score 0):

You use this function to change status bar colors, it's a kind of hack to deal with status bar ;). If you are using one theme status bar in whole app , call this function from didFinishLaunching in AppDelegate.

```
func changeStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor, contentColor:UIColor) {

    if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        statusBar.setValue(contentColor, forKey: "foregroundColor")
    }
}
```